# Is there a way to bypass the error "as 'this' argument discards qualifiers?

Tags: c++

I need to remove Duplications from a const Vector, by creating my own function. I have the process correct and it will remove the duplicates if I remove const, but I need to keep it in the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

vector<string> removeDuplicates(const vector<string>& s);

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Test 1. Output should be - to be or not is the question 
    vector<string> line1 = {"to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be", "is", "the", "question"} ;
    vector<string> result1  = removeDuplicates(line1);
    for(int i = 0; i < result1.size(); i++) {
        cout << result1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Test 2. Output should be - of all the gin joints in towns world she walks into mine 
    vector<string> line2 = {"of", "all", "the", "gin", "joints", "in", "all", "the", "towns", "in", "all", "the", "world", "she", "walks", "into", "mine"} ;
    vector<string> result2  = removeDuplicates(line2);
    for(int i = 0; i < result2.size(); i++) {
        cout << result2[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

vector<string> removeDuplicates(const vector<string>& s) {
    // Your code here
    for(int i =0; i <s.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        if(s[i+1] == s[j]){
            s.erase(s.begin() +i+1);    
        break;
        }
        else continue;}
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Your two requirements are in conflict. `const` means "You may not modify the object." But you want to modify the object by removing duplicates. You'll have to reconcile the two conflicting requirements somehow. For example, maybe `removeDuplicates` should return a new vector rather than modifying the existing one.

Comment: Why not use `std::unique_copy` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) instead of writing your own function.

Comment: @phil1970 I have to create my own function

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix.

```
vector<string> removeDuplicates(const vector<string>& s) {
    vector<string> r(s);
    for(int i =0; i <r.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        if(r[i+1] == r[j]){
            r.erase(r.begin() +i+1);    
        break;
        }
        else continue;}
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: That did get past the error, but it does not supply the correct output

Comment: That sounds a lot like you might have another question to ask, @lexonXV , but I'd kick it around in my brain for a while first. Explore what the program is doing by working through the logic, maybe stepping through it with a debugger, and trying to fix it myself first.

Comment: I got it able to edit the new vector, but now i do not understand why it is removing incorrect words, I only added a second vector and made it equal to the Const Vector

Comment: Your second loop is incorrect. You check previous elements again and again: 0 till 0, 0 till 1, 0 till 2...